# Tools for A9G GPRS+GPS Module of chinese AI thinker

Tags: gps, gprs

The link for downloading Windows tools is dead.
https://github.com/Ai-Thinker-Open/GPRS_CSDTK

And I tried to build it on ubuntu 16 follow this link
https://ai-thinker-open.github.io/GPRS_C_SDK_DOC/en/c-sdk/installation_linux.html

But there is no option for 8955 chip in CoolWatcher burner. It just has 8808, 8808s, 8809, 8810, 8810-AP, Gallite-8805, Gallite-8806.

So can I add 8955 into CoolWatcher manually? What are the good alternative GPS module which have tools to change the firmware directly? Did chinese AI thinker company dead?
Thanks!